# How to get a particular element from Queue?

Tags: java, collections

Unlike `ArrayList`, there is no `get(int index)` method in `Queue` to retrieve the element at specified position.

Anybody please tell me how to achieve this in `Queue`?

Thanks.

Comment: Downcast to your specific `Queue` implementation, if it supports that operation.

Comment: Queue is FIFO. Why would you have `get(int index)` method? Change your data structure to appropriate one.

Comment: Queue is FIFO . you cannot acheive this in a queue. It will break the functionality of a queue.

Comment: Use LinkedList. It's a perfect queue that can be accessed from the middle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove elements from the Queue until you reach the needed one. You can re-add the removed elements at the end of the queue or put them in a different queue (and add the rest after you reached the needed element).

You really shouldn't be using a Queue like that, though!

```
public static <T> T get(Queue<T> queue, int index) {
    synchronized (queue) {
        if (queue == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int size = queue.size();
        if (index < 0 || size < index + 1) {
            return null;
        }

        T element = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (i == index) {
                element = queue.remove();
            } else {
                queue.add(queue.remove());
            }
        }

        return element;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Accessing elements by index is not part of the concept of a queue.

If you need to access elements by index, you want a list, not a queue.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static Object retrieveElement(int index, Queue q) {
    Iterator it = q.iterator();
    int count = 0;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Object e = it.next();
        if (count == index) {
            it.remove();
            return e;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T> T getFromQueue(Queue<T> queue, int index){
    if(index>=queue.size()){
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index="+index+",size="+queue.size());
    }
    Queue<T> queueCopy = new LinkedList<T>(queue);
    for(int i=0; i<index; i++){
        queueCopy.remove();
    }
    return queueCopy.peek();
}
```

Comment: Why are you choosing to use a `LinkedList` as opposed to an `ArrayList`? You're spending roughly the same amount of CPU+memory with either instantiation. However, there is definitely a much higher cost with the use of a `for` loop instead of accessing the element directly by index within the `ArrayList` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Queues operate in a first in first out (FIFO) manner therefore in order to access a particular element the elements must be removed and stored in a secondary queue until the element being searched for is identified

Answer (score 0):

```
private static  List<Individual> queueToList(Queue<Individual> archive) {
      List<Individual> list = new LinkedList<Individual>();
      Iterator<Individual> it = archive.iterator();
      while(it.hasNext()){
         list.add(it.next());
      }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the concept of Queue is FIFO(First In First Out).So accessing the particular index or the element in the queue is not possible. The other way is to get a particular element you need to delete it unless and until you get it.

Answer (score 0):

As many others said, if you are writing something from scratch you may have a wrong approach.

I had to refactor a legacy application and for different reasons that I'm not willing to share I've got the same problem.

I solved using the following:

```
Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
String element = new ArrayList<String>(queue).get(desiredIndex);

// if you are sure there is no null elements you can do the following
String[] element = queue.toArray()[desiredIndex]
```

And I know is not a cheap operation, In my case I'm restricting the size of the queue a < 3 to avoid huge performance hits.

The idea of removing and re-adding to queue like others suggested is okay if the order does not matter, but in my specific problem it does.

Answer (score -2):

10 years late, but I was just looking for the same thing. It looks like since the underlying implementation of a regular queue in java is a linked list you can get a specific indexed element by doing something like:

```java
queue.peek()[index]
```