# how to remove a specific element from queue in java(not priority queue)

Tags: java, queue

How I can  remove a specific element from `queue` in `java(not priority queue)`.There is no functionality of removing `queue.remove(object)`. Please help me in this.

```
Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
queue.add("hello");
queue.add("world");
queue.add("ranjeet");
```

I want to remove "world" from it.

Comment: can you add the code to show where the problem and help you to solve that

Comment: queue.remove("world"); this line is working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Queue Interface

The queue interface only allows you to remove elements from the head of the queue.
See the description of the API at:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#remove()

The whole purpose of the queue data structure is to push items to the tail and remove them from the head (as a real queue works).

You should use a different data structure / collection object type.

Another option would be to remove all the items of the queue and put them in another queue (except the item you want to remove).

Finally, another would be to make your own queue implementation adding the extra method.

### LinkedList

I linkedlist is an implementation that implements the Queue interface but it also implements other interfaces.

You could use the method:

> **remove(Object o)** 
>   Removes the first occurrence of the specified element
>   from this list, if it is present. If this list does not contain the
>   element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the
>   lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))
>   (if such an element exists). Returns true if this list contained the
>   specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result
>   of the call).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

You could change your code to:

```
LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
```

OR

```
List<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
```

### Why are you using a Queue/LinkedList?

The main question is why are you using a Queue/Linkedlist?
It seems that also a basic list could be suitable for what you want. 
If you want to remove intermediate items, a linkedlist is not the most suitable.

### LinkedList

Implements both interfaces of List and Queue.
See:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html
- http://i.prntscr.com/fUucDm_JQtm9ye3e3L3bZw.png

Comment: Actually this is only one part of code..I have to use functionality of queue in other parts.That's why I am using queue.

Comment: @Ranjeet Kumar yadav , if you want to remove intermediate elements you should be using a list. However, if you insist on using a queue, the solution is to re-insert all elements in a new queue (except the one you don't want). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22454237/1688441

Answer (score 0):

Correct. `Queue` does not have a method to remove a **specific** object (at a certain index, or that is equal to some provided argument):

> Queues typically, but do not necessarily, order elements in a FIFO (first-in-first-out) manner. ... Whatever the ordering used, the **head** of the queue is that element which would be removed by a call to remove() or poll(). In a FIFO queue, all new elements are inserted at the **tail** of the queue. Other kinds of queues may use different placement rules. Every Queue implementation must specify its ordering properties.

The reason for that is simple: `Queue` is not a "random" access data structure. It only supports removing elements from head resp. tail; depending on the implementation.

In that sense the answer is one of:

- you either have to "pop" all entries of the queue up to the one to remove, to then **add** them back
- you change the underlying data structure to something that allows "random" remove actions

And please note: your code shows a potential solution. Simply change it to:

```
List<String> strings = new LinkedList<>();
```

and all of a sudden you can `remove()` objects by index or "by value".

To my knowledge, there is *no* interfaces that combines both interfaces (List and Queue). But of course, there are implementations, such as `LinkedList` that actually do that.

Comment: can you suggest me some other data structure which act like queue and also able to remove element using object reference.

Comment: @GhostCat not exactly correct. LinkedList Implements both interfaces of List and Queue. If he just replaces the variable definition it will work.  `LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();` I think you meant there is no interface that implements both. @Ghostcat , see: http://i.prntscr.com/fUucDm_JQtm9ye3e3L3bZw.png

Comment: Yes, I was in hurry writing it down. Changed and fixed. And you got a nice answer btw ,-)

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you. You too! Unrelated, is that your real cat? Looks similar to a russian blue. Looks amazing!

Comment: Yes. My cat. But calling him Russian Blue almost makes me want to undo my upvote on your answer ;-O. He is a [chartreux](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartreux) ... I have to link to the GERMAN wikipedia article - the English one only shows a picture of cat that is "most likely a Russian Blue". Crazy world.

Answer (score 0):

`queue.remove(obj)` won't work when you've instantiated your Queue obj as a Linked List.
You've to use

```
queue.remove(idx)
```